# Need help incrementing the getHour Method

Tags: java, methods, time

I am currently trying to increment my code to add a second and if the second changes the hour and minute, it will be reflected. here is my current code. I know the issue that I am having lies in the get hour method because it is the only one that isn't incrementing. Thank you for the help.

```
    public class Time2
{
   private int hour;   // 0 - 23
   private int minute; // 0 - 59
   private int second; // 0 - 59
   private int seconds;

   // Time2 no-argument constructor: initializes each instance variable 
   // to zero; ensures that Time2 objects start in a consistent state
   public Time2()
   {
      this( 0, 0, 0 ); // invoke Time2 constructor with three arguments
   } // end Time2 no-argument constructor

   // Time2 constructor: hour supplied, minute and second defaulted to 0
   public Time2( int h ) 
   { 
      this( h, 0, 0 ); // invoke Time2 constructor with three arguments
   } // end Time2 one-argument constructor

   // Time2 constructor: hour and minute supplied, second defaulted to 0
   public Time2( int h, int m ) 
   { 
      this( h, m, 0 ); // invoke Time2 constructor with three arguments
   } // end Time2 two-argument constructor 

   // Time2 constructor: hour, minute and second supplied
   public Time2( int h, int m, int s ) 
   { 
      setTime( h, m, s ); // invoke setTime to validate time
   } // end Time2 three-argument constructor 

   // Time2 constructor: another Time2 object supplied
   public Time2( Time2 time )
   {
      // invoke Time2 three-argument constructor
      this( time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond() );
   } // end Time2 constructor with a Time2 object argument

   // Set Methods
   // set a new time value using universal time; ensure that 
   // the data remains consistent by setting invalid values to zero
   public void setTime( int h, int m, int s )
   {
      setHour( h );   // set the hour
      setMinute( m ); // set the minute
      setSecond( s ); // set the second
   } // end method setTime

   // validate and set hour 
   public void setHour( int h ) 
   { 
      hour = ( ( h >= 0 && h < 24 ) ? h : 0 ); 
   } // end method setHour

   // validate and set minute 
   public void setMinute( int m ) 
   { 
      minute = ( ( m >= 0 && m < 60 ) ? m : 0 ); 
   } // end method setMinute

   // validate and set second 
   public void setSecond( int s ) 
   { 
      second = ( ( s >= 0 && s < 60 ) ? s : 0 ); 
   } // end method setSecond

   // Get Methods
   // get hour value
   public int getHour() 
   { 
       if(minute > 59)
       {
         hour++;
       }

      return hour; 
   } // end method getHour

   // get minute value
   public int getMinute() 
   { 
       if(second > 59)
       {
          minute++;
       }
       if(minute > 59)
       {
          minute = 00;
       }

      return minute; 
   } // end method getMinute

   // get second value
   public int getSecond() 
   {
       if(second > 59)
       {
           second = 00;
       }
      return second++; 
   } // end method getSecond

   // convert to String in universal-time format (HH:MM:SS)
   public String toUniversalString()
   {
      return String.format( 
         "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond() );
   } // end method toUniversalString

   // convert to String in standard-time format (H:MM:SS AM or PM)
   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format( "%d:%02d:%02d %s", 
         ( (getHour() == 0 || getHour() == 12) ? 12 : getHour() % 12 ),
         getMinute(), getSecond(), ( getHour() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM" ) );
   } // end method toString
} // end class Time2
```

The results that I am getting from my test app are:

```
public class Time2Test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Time2 t1 = new Time2(); // 00:00:00
      Time2 t2 = new Time2(2); // 02:00:00
      Time2 t3 = new Time2(21, 34); // 21:34:00
      Time2 t4 = new Time2(12, 59, 59); // 12:25:42
      Time2 t5 = new Time2(t4); // 12:25:42

      System.out.println("Constructed with:");
      displayTime("t1: all default arguments", t1);
      displayTime("t2: hour specified; default minute and second", t2);
      displayTime("t3: hour and minute specified; default second", t3);
      displayTime("t4: hour, minute and second specified", t4);
      displayTime("t5: Time2 object t4 specified", t5);

      // attempt to initialize t6 with invalid values
      try
      {
         Time2 t6 = new Time2(27, 74, 99); // invalid values
      } 
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         System.out.printf("%nException while initializing t6: %s%n",
            e.getMessage());
      } 
   } 

   // displays a Time2 object in 24-hour and 12-hour formats
   private static void displayTime(String header, Time2 t)
   {
      System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n   %s%n",
         header, t.toUniversalString(), t.toString());
   } 
} // end class Time2Test
```

Output:

```
Constructed with:
t1: all default arguments
   00:00:00
   12:00:01 AM
t2: hour specified; default minute and second
   02:00:00
   2:00:01 AM
t3: hour and minute specified; default second
   21:34:00
   9:34:01 PM
t4: hour, minute and second specified
   12:00:00
   12:00:01 PM
t5: Time2 object t4 specified
   12:59:59
   12:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Why do you have both `second` and `seconds`, out of interest? And is this an academic exercise? If not, I suggest you use an existing time API, such as Joda Time.

Comment: Your getMinute() method is screwy. You test for minute > 59 twice. Should be less than in the first conditional. Fix that first and see what magic ensues. And yes, yes, yes to Joda time. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, do not change the object state in a getter.  Plus, provide the code for you test application.

Comment: Yes, this is a assignment for school so I wouldn't be able to use Joda Time. I originally was trying to go a different way with the second seconds instance but decided to not use it.

Comment: I have edited my code to also show the test app. As you can see by last last output, i have the seconds and minutes incrementing up like they should, but I can not get the hour to do the same.

Comment: protip:  don't change the state of your object in a method that begins with the word `get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
getMinute(), getSecond(), ( getHour() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM" )
```

If minute is greater than 59, the getMinute method will change minute to 0. Then when getHour is called, minute is 0, so hour isn't incremented.

As others have stated, do not modify variables in getters. It causes all kinds of havoc.